# SQLite for Java not updating rows correctly

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite

Good afternoon. I've got a problem with my DB implementing it on Java. I want to update these two columns. The row Puntos doesn't occasionate any kind of problem, and every time I run the executeUpdate(), the row gets incremented. However, in 'Victorias totales', the executeUpdate() method behaves as if it was just like

```
UPDATE EquiposIBAI 
SET Puntos=Puntos + 3, 'Victorias Totales' = 1 
WHERE NOMBRE='SD Eibar' AND fk_CodLiga=5;
```

I mean, the value doesn't get incremented, it gets just overwritten.

```
UPDATE EquiposIBAI 
SET Puntos=Puntos + 3, 'Victorias Totales' = 'Victorias Totales' + 1 
WHERE NOMBRE='SD Eibar' AND fk_CodLiga=5;
```

Is there any way to fix it?(I'm using SQLite for Java)
Thx in advance.

Comment: You have a problem using single quotes for a column name.  Are you checking the error status of your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite you need to escape column names using either double quotes (`"`), square brackets (`[]`), or back ticks.

I would use the double quotes for simplicity (it's the *standard* SQL way), as in:

```
UPDATE EquiposIBAI 
SET Puntos=Puntos + 3, "Victorias Totales" = "Victorias Totales" + 1 
WHERE NOMBRE='SD Eibar' AND fk_CodLiga=5;
```

Single quotes are for string literals, and they are well used in the third line.

Alternatively, I would avoid (when possible) to use spaces in column names, or well... any special character for that matter. In this case, I would change the column name to `victorias_totales`.

Comment: The thing is that I want to introduce the whole command into a String in Java. It worked in SQLite, but I'm going to try it putting the string in Java. Thanks!

Comment: In Java you must prepend a backslash to each double quote in a String literal. The SQL text `"Victorias Totales"` must be written in a Java String as `\"Victorias Totales\"`.